# Upload a file with Tastypie Django with android client

Tags: android, http, tastypie, multipart

I am programming an API in Tastypie and I want to upload files with multi-part http request.

I've created this function in an async task in my android file:

```
public JSONObject getJSONObejctPOSTFILE(String url,
        List<NameValuePair> params, String key) {


    HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.getThreadSafeClient();
    HttpPost requestPOST = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.194/api/v1/newresource/?format=json");
    //the request is definied
    requestPOST.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    requestPOST.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    try {

            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
            multipartEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody("new.jpg"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("image"));
            File image = new File(DataObjectToNet.getList_objects().get(0).getData());
            FileBody fil = new FileBody(image);
            multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(image));
            requestPOST.setEntity(multipartEntity);

            client.execute(requestPOST, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());

        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
    return null;
}
```

the api in tastypie is the code produced in the visit https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/42. The problem is when I send a file with android client, the server give me the next response:

```
 {"error_message": "Invalid boundary in multipart: None", "traceback": "Traceback (most         recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 397, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1161, in post_list\n    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n  File \"/var/www/html/patit_server_app/api/api.py\", line 346, in deserialize\n    data = request.POST.copy()\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py\", line 69, in _get_post\n    self._load_post_and_files()\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py\", line 360, in _load_post_and_files\n    self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py\", line 319, in parse_file_upload\n    parser = MultiPartParser(META, post_data, self.upload_handlers, self.encoding)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py\", line 65, in __init__\n    raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary)\n\nMultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None\n"}
```

Wath it's this problem? The android http request it's a bed format?. I know that tastypie it's a bad way to upload files to my server, but I would like to do this at this form.

The Tastypie API is:

```
class MultipartResource(object):
   def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
       if not format:
            format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')

       if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
           return request.POST

       if format.startswith('multipart'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)

        return data

       return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

class ResourceNewResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):
    fil = Base64FileField('data')

    class Meta:
        queryset = res.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'newresource'
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        allowed_methods = ['get','post']
        always_return_data=True
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Can someone help me to upload android files to the tastypie django server?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally could upload the file, but I didn't use the tastypie API. I utilize the Django file upload. The code to upload the file that I use was:

```
def upload_file(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':

        print "file"
        new_file = Resource(name=request.FILES['file'].name,data=request.FILES['file'],type = "ARCHIVE",create_date=timezone.now(), route=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

        new_file.save()

        response_data={result":"OK"}
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')


  else:
    response_data={"success": "No a post request"}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: How did you integrate this into tastypie?

Comment: This has not integration with tastypie. Is the client who wait until the file is uploaded and then send a http to tastypie API with the url  given by Django upload system.